# Media Library, hook on delete user action

Tags: media-library

I need to run my function when a user deletes a media file from the media library. Is there a hook I can use?

Would appreciate it if someone  could please point me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: I did some searching and it looks I should be hooking on before_delete_post. Will give it a go and reposrt back here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more appropriate hook may be `delete_attachment($post_id)`.  You may also need to hook `edit_attachment`.  Note that the `post_id` is that of the attachment type post, not the page/blog post to which the media is attached (if any).

In case you want to know when media is added, hook `add_attachment($post_id)`.  Note that `add_attachment` is called before intermediate size files are generated but after the media has been placed in the upload directory.

Comment: Indeed you are right Davidj! Thanks for that. I fixed my code and it works much better.